# Designing an algorithm to sort n strings in O(dn)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, array-algorithms

How can I design an algorithm to sort n strings in O(dn) where d is the #of characters in a longest string?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

1. Create an empty trie.
2. Loop over all strings, and place them in it.
3. Iterate over all the trie's values in order, and output them (see [Trie complexity and searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032116/trie-complexity-and-searching) as suggested below by Jean-Baptiste Yunès).

The complexity of 1 is constant. The complexity of each of 2 and 3 is *O(dn)*.

Comment: 3rd point is not clear. How are you making sure the strings are sorted

Comment: @SauravSahu It's a pretty simple recursive function (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685687/how-to-print-all-words-in-a-trie) an implementation). Starting at the node, recursively visit all children in order, while keeping track of current prefix. When you hit a leaf, output the total string along the path.

Comment: Complement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032116/trie-complexity-and-searching

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Thanks for the useful link! Added inline